# Gerar alert do Twitter-Bootstrap dentro do próprio script ao clicar em um botão

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar e abrir um alerta (.alert) do Twitter-Bootstrap com uma mensagem personalizada dentro do próprio script, sem ter de criar a div personalizada fora do script e chamá-la? Ao clicar no botão "meuInput", criar e abrir o alert com uma mensagem com o exemplo abaixo:

```
<input type='text' name='meuInput' id='meuInput'>

<button id='meuBtn' class='btn btn-default'>Continuar</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var meuInput = $("#meuInput").val();

    $("#meuBtn").on('click',function(){

      if(meuInput == "") {
        [ chamar um alerta com a mensagem personalizada dentro do script ]      
      }

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem um problema no seu código que verificava somente o valor do `input` no carregamento da página, mas, era só colocar no evento do botão para que fosse conferido a todo momento do `click` no botão se tem valor digitado no `input`, ***exemplo***:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#meuBtn").on('click', function() {
    var meuInput = $("#meuInput").val();
    if (meuInput == "") {
      $(".bs-example-modal-sm").modal('show');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<input type='text' name='meuInput' id='meuInput' class="form-control">
<button id='meuBtn' class='btn btn-default'>Continuar</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class=modal-header> <button type=button class=close data-dismiss=modal aria-label=Close><span aria-hidden=true>&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class=modal-title id="myLargeModalLabel">Alerta</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Digite meu Input</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, funcionou sim, mas é o uso de alert, e não modal, e gostaria mesmo é de que a mensagem do alert, no caso do seu exemplo, fosse passada direto de uma var do javascript para div.modal-body.

Comment: @EliseuB passar qual valor?

Comment: No exemplo que fiz, o input "meuInput" é verificado se está vazio, então passar valor para dentro do alert, por exemplo "O campo meuInput está em branco". Consegui aqui como fazer, obrigado pela ajuda.